# How to sign a .NET Framework ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clickonce

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application that I built for a client, and I need it to be from a trusted publisher. How do I go about acquiring an [Authenticode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing#Implementations) certificate and sign my application with it? So that when the application is launched, it's from a trusted publisher?

How do I install the certificate? Do I have to install it on my development server or does it matter where I install it?

How does the whole process work? I don't want to spend 3-5 hundred dollars on a certificate, and install something wrong and be out of luck.

Are there good tutorials on purchasing and installing a certificate and signing a ClickOnce application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recently went through this process. A certificate is not that expensive - we got a code-signing certificate for less than a $100.

After you have the certificate, follow the FAQ [HOWTO: Code signing how-to](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1654)* to sign your code (binaries).

After that, you have to go to project properties -> Signing and upload your certificate there as well (it's for ClickOnce). You can skip code signing though and sign ClickOnce only.

ClickOnce **requires** a certificate for code signing, and others will not work, see *[ClickOnce Deployment and Authenticode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-and-authenticode)*:

> For ClickOnce applications, you must have an Authenticode certificate
> that is valid for code signing; if you attempt to sign a ClickOnce
> application with another type of certificate, such as a digital e-mail
> certificate, it will not work.

**Jan'18 UPDATE:
StartSSL is not trusted anymore,** and I did NOT find any free (or similar to what StartSSL was offering) code signing certificates. At the end of the day, I went with ksoftware.net - $84/year for Comodo code-signing certificate (but you need to have DUNS record available for them to check!)

Comment: Which certificate would be sufficient for code signing, in terms of cheapest price?

Comment: Hi avs009, the link to FAQ is dead.

Comment: yes, startSSL is dead too. See my update - I bolded it.

Comment: @avs099 the link `HOWTO: Code signing how-to` is still dead.

Comment: startSSL is dead for many years now, please see my updates and comments.