# Sign application with a certificate in ClickOnce deployment

Tags: windows, certificate, clickonce

For my Windows-based application, I would like to use [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) as the deployment technology. My application will be distributed via the Internet.

In the article [ClickOnce and Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms172240.aspx), I read that:

> For ClickOnce applications, you must have an Authenticode certificate
>   that is valid for code signing. You can obtain a certificate for code
>   signing in one of three ways:
>
> 1. Purchase one from a certificate vendor.
> 2. Receive one from a group in your organization responsible for creating
>      digital certificates.
> 3. Generate your own certificate with MakeCert.exe, which is included
>      with the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).

In my case, number 2 is not applicable.

As I read a few rows later:

> *By default,* ClickOnce applications *signed with self-certs and deployed
>   over the Internet* cannot utilize Trusted Application Deployment.

(Emphasis mine.)

I cannot understand the meaning of this *by default*. Is the option #3 possible or not in my case?

And then, to understand all the possibilities, what does the #1 imply ? ("Purchase one from a certificate vendor") What kind of certificate should I buy? Which [certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) can be recommended? Depending on what I should choose? How much does a certificate cost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It must be a "Microsoft Authenticode Certificate". It allows us to sign all kinds of Windows executables and code, including `.exe`, `.cab`, `.dll`, `.ocx`, and `.xpi` files.

It is not mandatory to sign an application, but if we do it our users won’t see a warning message stating that the author of the software is unknown.

Microsoft Authenticode Certificates need to be issued by a trusted certificate authority. Unfortunately, the prices are quite expensive. More information and some examples 
are on page *[Microsoft Authenticode Certificates](http://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html)*.

**UPDATE** I purchased the certificate through [KSoftware](http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/), which is a [Comodo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodo_Group) retailer. The price is quite good compared to alternatives: $95/year. The process is faster than I expected: I applied in the morning and in the evening my certificate was already available. (For those interested, I followed [this step-by-step guide](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/codesigning101/).)

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer to Stack Overflow question *How to sign a ClickOnce application*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610556/how-to-sign-a-clickonce-application/9610744#9610744).

I would definitely suggest getting a proper code-signing certificate - your application install screen will look much nicer in this case.

`StartCom CA is closed since Jan. 1st, 2018` <strike>I got my code-signing certificate from http://startssl.com - and it was $100 or so in total (and you get wild-card domain certificate for your website as well as a bonus).</strike>

It's much cheaper than going with [VeriSign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisign) or [TrustWave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trustwave_Holdings).

Comment: How did you generate the CSR for the code signing certificate?