# Using .NET 4.5 C# to create a .exe file then write code to it in c# then open it

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i would like to know if i can write code into a File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Name.exe") that is in c#.

My purpose for this is I need 2 applications, one is a launcher and one is a updater, i originaly had a File.Exist looking for the updater so no errors occured, but i would like it so you only need the launcher at first then it adds the other folders and files when you first open it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a tour(http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the help center(http://stackoverflow.com/help). You might also want to read How to Ask(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just add all the other files you need as embedded rescources

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel try using [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx)

If you're going to need a certificate if your app is to be [signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610556/how-to-sign-a-clickonce-application) and publicly distributed. You can work with a [test certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx) for development

Build your app, right-click on the main project and pick Publish (also on the Build menu), follow the [wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)

The target location you pick will end up having an `app.application` file and some folders, one for each version you publish. You can put these files on a file server somewhere and share the link to the .application file with your users. Every time you publish their app will get updated the next time they use it.

---

If reinventing the wheel is your thing you can build your app, make another project checks a link for a file that contains a version, compares with the local version and downloads if newer, then launches the downloaded exe.... just like clickonce